# How can I fix SequelizeDatabaseError: syntax error at or near ')' in my postgres query?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have this query snippet that gives an error, but I know it works perfectly because I tested it in dbeaver
Error: (node:152373) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: syntax error at or near ")".

Query:

```
   AND u.status = '${status || 1}'
   AND e.deleted_at IS NULL
   AND (
     SELECT COUNT(lup.id)
     FROM lesson_user_progress lup
     WHERE lup.id_course = c.id
       AND lup.id_user = e.id_user 
   ) = 0
```

Postgres, Nodejs and Sequelize my techs

Eu tentei colocar is not exists, but same error.

Comment: does your query really begin with `AND ( SELECT`... ?

Comment: it is a large and functional query, this section is just the end of it.
AND u.status = '${status || 1}'
            AND e.deleted_at IS NULL
AND (
        SELECT COUNT(lup.id)
        FROM lesson_user_progress lup
        WHERE lup.id_course = c.id
          AND lup.id_user = e.id_user
      ) = 0

Comment: Just get the generated SQL and check it in DBeaver